# How to plot function with an $n$

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to plot the following function:

```
f=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n
where
f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
        n^2(x-n+1/n^2)  & \quad \text{if } n-1/n^2\leq x\leq n,\\
        n^2(-x+n+1/n^2) & \quad \text{if } n\leq x\leq n+1/n^2,\\
        0               & \quad \text{else}.
       \end{cases}
```

Each f_n is a triangle so the whole graph would be like that: (I drawed the first two triangles without interception wrongly)
[image: Graph]

I utilized Tikz to create the first two triangles in the following way:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = left,
xlabel = $x$,
ylabel = {$f(x)$},
]
\addplot [
domain=0:1, 
samples=100, 
color=blue,
]
{x};
\addplot [
domain=1:1.75, 
samples=100, 
color=blue,
]
{-x+2};
\addplot [
domain=1.75:2, 
samples=100, 
color=blue,
]
{3*x-5};
\addplot [
domain=2:2.25, 
samples=100, 
color=blue,
]
{-4*x+9};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I just can't figure out how to do the third triangle.

Comment: You do not need `pgfplots` for this. Simply draw your triangles. But your functions overlap : the first triangle ends at 2, the second one starts at 2-1/4. So the graph of f wil not be this one :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this?

[image]

i didn't reconstruct triangles from your equation but use your mwe and sketch. since you like to draw simple triangles, i suggest to use coordinates for theirs  significant points (if they are wrong, please adopt them to correct values):

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = left,
xlabel = $x$,
ylabel = {$f(x)$},
xmax = 4.5,
ymax = 1.5,
xtick = {0,1,2,4},
xticklabels = {0,1,2,$n$},
ytick = {1},
no marks,
samples = 10,
]
\addplot +[blue]    coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (1.75,0)};
\addplot +[blue]    coordinates {(1.75,0) (2,1) (2.25,0)};
\addplot +[blue]    coordinates {(3.95,0) (4,1) (4.05,0)};
    \draw[dashed,very thin] (0,1) -- (4,1);
    \draw[loosely dotted,very thick] (2.5,0.5) -- (3.5,0.5);
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```